# Application directory access

Tags: c++, directory

Is there a way to grant a Windows C++ application read/write access to a directory that the unprivileged user running the application would otherwise not have access to? Writing and communicating with a service that performs the actual file access will work, but I'd prefer not to throw code at the problem if there's an easier / more straightforward solution.

Comment: No, permissions are always user/group based not application based. I for one would either require the user to be part of a group that has access to your resource (directory) or use a `sudo`-like mechanism (if that exists on Windows). But maybe I'm thinking too "unix-y" and your service idea would be better, dunno.

Comment: Can you not just put the file/folder somewhere more accessible?

Comment: I'd actually like the directory _less_ accessible. The application writes logs and other data that unprivileged users should not be able to modify except under control of the program.

Windows does have an "impersonation" feature that is probably like sudo, though it does require you to know the password of the user that you're impersonating, which presents security problems of its own.

Answer (score 0):

No

the purpose of security is to make sure that directories and other items are not accessed when they shouldn't be.